# Power Query Pagination

Tags: pagination, powerbi, powerquery

I'm new to Power Query. I'm looking to create an iterative pagination script for my business case.

A quick note, I cannot provide the API key or Endpoint that I'm using, so you will not be able to test it on your end, I will have to test the code on my side. I am seeking some suggested code, which I will test on my side.

I have a working request code for one page shown below (note all of the `Expand...` stuff which is screwing me up in figuring out how to paginate this request). The results are of email related data for context:

```
// Working for 1 page
let
    // Define some variables
    _url = "https://www.randomURLNOTWORKING.com/events?before=9999999999",
    _headers = [authorization="Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"],

    // Request the JSON response
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(_url, [Headers=_headers])),
    
    // Unpack the response
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromRecords({Source}),
    #"Expanded _pagination" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "_pagination", {"next"}, {"_pagination.next"}),
    #"Expanded _links" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _pagination", "_links", {"self"}, {"_links.self"}),
    #"Expanded _results" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded _links", "_results"),
    #"Expanded _results1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results", "_results", {"_links", "id", "type", "emitted_at", "conversation", "source", "target"}, {"_results._links", "_results.id", "_results.type", "_results.emitted_at", "_results.conversation", "_results.source", "_results.target"}),
    #"Expanded _results._links" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results1", "_results._links", {"self"}, {"_results._links.self"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results._links", "_results.conversation", {"_links", "id", "subject", "status", "assignee", "recipient", "tags", "links", "created_at", "is_private", "scheduled_reminders", "metadata"}, {"_results.conversation._links", "_results.conversation.id", "_results.conversation.subject", "_results.conversation.status", "_results.conversation.assignee", "_results.conversation.recipient", "_results.conversation.tags", "_results.conversation.links", "_results.conversation.created_at", "_results.conversation.is_private", "_results.conversation.scheduled_reminders", "_results.conversation.metadata"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation._links" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation", "_results.conversation._links", {"self", "related"}, {"_results.conversation._links.self", "_results.conversation._links.related"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation._links.related" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation._links", "_results.conversation._links.related", {"events", "followers", "messages", "comments", "inboxes", "last_message"}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.events", "_results.conversation._links.related.followers", "_results.conversation._links.related.messages", "_results.conversation._links.related.comments", "_results.conversation._links.related.inboxes", "_results.conversation._links.related.last_message"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation.recipient" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation._links.related", "_results.conversation.recipient", {"_links", "name", "handle", "role"}, {"_results.conversation.recipient._links", "_results.conversation.recipient.name", "_results.conversation.recipient.handle", "_results.conversation.recipient.role"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation.recipient._links" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation.recipient", "_results.conversation.recipient._links", {"related"}, {"_results.conversation.recipient._links.related"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation.recipient._links.related" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation.recipient._links", "_results.conversation.recipient._links.related", {"contact"}, {"_results.conversation.recipient._links.related.contact"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation.metadata" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation.recipient._links.related", "_results.conversation.metadata", {}, {}),
    #"Expanded _results.source" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation.metadata", "_results.source", {"_meta", "data"}, {"_results.source._meta", "_results.source.data"}),
    #"Expanded _results.source._meta" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.source", "_results.source._meta", {"type"}, {"_results.source._meta.type"}),
    #"Expanded _results.target" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.source._meta", "_results.target", {"_meta", "data"}, {"_results.target._meta", "_results.target.data"}),
    #"Expanded _results.target._meta" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.target", "_results.target._meta", {"type"}, {"_results.target._meta.type"}),
    #"Expanded _results.target.data" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.target._meta", "_results.target.data", {"_links", "id", "type", "is_inbound", "name", "highlight", "is_private", "is_visible_in_conversation_lists", "updated_at", "created_at", "blurb", "body", "text", "error_type", "version", "subject", "draft_mode", "metadata", "posted_at", "author", "recipients", "attachments", "signature", "is_draft", "email", "username", "first_name", "last_name", "is_admin", "is_available", "is_blocked", "custom_fields"}, {"_results.target.data._links", "_results.target.data.id", "_results.target.data.type", "_results.target.data.is_inbound", "_results.target.data.name", "_results.target.data.highlight", "_results.target.data.is_private", "_results.target.data.is_visible_in_conversation_lists", "_results.target.data.updated_at", "_results.target.data.created_at", "_results.target.data.blurb", "_results.target.data.body", "_results.target.data.text", "_results.target.data.error_type", "_results.target.data.version", "_results.target.data.subject", "_results.target.data.draft_mode", "_results.target.data.metadata", "_results.target.data.posted_at", "_results.target.data.author", "_results.target.data.recipients", "_results.target.data.attachments", "_results.target.data.signature", "_results.target.data.is_draft", "_results.target.data.email", "_results.target.data.username", "_results.target.data.first_name", "_results.target.data.last_name", "_results.target.data.is_admin", "_results.target.data.is_available", "_results.target.data.is_blocked", "_results.target.data.custom_fields"}),
    #"Expanded _results.target.data._links" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.target.data", "_results.target.data._links", {"self", "related"}, {"_results.target.data._links.self", "_results.target.data._links.related"}),
    #"Expanded _results.target.data._links.related" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.target.data._links", "_results.target.data._links.related", {"conversation", "message_seen", "mentions", "inboxes", "conversations", "owner", "parent_tag", "children", "message_replied_to"}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.conversation", "_results.target.data._links.related.message_seen", "_results.target.data._links.related.mentions", "_results.target.data._links.related.inboxes", "_results.target.data._links.related.conversations", "_results.target.data._links.related.owner", "_results.target.data._links.related.parent_tag", "_results.target.data._links.related.children", "_results.target.data._links.related.message_replied_to"}),
    #"Expanded _results.target.data.metadata" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.target.data._links.related", "_results.target.data.metadata", {}, {}),
    #"Expanded _results.target.data.custom_fields" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.target.data.metadata", "_results.target.data.custom_fields", {}, {}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded _results.target.data.custom_fields",{{"_pagination.next", type text}, {"_links.self", type text}, {"_results._links.self", type text}, {"_results.id", type text}, {"_results.type", type text}, {"_results.emitted_at", type number}, {"_results.conversation._links.self", type text}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.events", type text}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.followers", type text}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.messages", type text}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.comments", type text}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.inboxes", type text}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.last_message", type text}, {"_results.conversation.id", type text}, {"_results.conversation.subject", type text}, {"_results.conversation.status", type text}, {"_results.conversation.assignee", type any}, {"_results.conversation.recipient._links.related.contact", type text}, {"_results.conversation.recipient.name", type text}, {"_results.conversation.recipient.handle", type text}, {"_results.conversation.recipient.role", type text}, {"_results.conversation.tags", type any}, {"_results.conversation.links", type any}, {"_results.conversation.created_at", type number}, {"_results.conversation.is_private", type logical}, {"_results.conversation.scheduled_reminders", type any}, {"_results.source._meta.type", type text}, {"_results.source.data", type any}, {"_results.target._meta.type", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.self", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.conversation", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.message_seen", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.mentions", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.inboxes", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.conversations", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.owner", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.parent_tag", type any}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.children", type any}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.message_replied_to", type text}, {"_results.target.data.id", type text}, {"_results.target.data.type", type text}, {"_results.target.data.is_inbound", type logical}, {"_results.target.data.name", type text}, {"_results.target.data.highlight", type any}, {"_results.target.data.is_private", type logical}, {"_results.target.data.is_visible_in_conversation_lists", type logical}, {"_results.target.data.updated_at", type number}, {"_results.target.data.created_at", type number}, {"_results.target.data.blurb", type text}, {"_results.target.data.body", type text}, {"_results.target.data.text", type text}, {"_results.target.data.error_type", type any}, {"_results.target.data.version", type any}, {"_results.target.data.subject", type text}, {"_results.target.data.draft_mode", type any}, {"_results.target.data.posted_at", type number}, {"_results.target.data.author", type any}, {"_results.target.data.recipients", type any}, {"_results.target.data.attachments", type any}, {"_results.target.data.signature", type any}, {"_results.target.data.is_draft", type logical}, {"_results.target.data.email", type text}, {"_results.target.data.username", type text}, {"_results.target.data.first_name", type text}, {"_results.target.data.last_name", type text}, {"_results.target.data.is_admin", type logical}, {"_results.target.data.is_available", type logical}, {"_results.target.data.is_blocked", type logical}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Please note that I have looked at all of the articles linked below, but am still having trouble getting the correct syntax as this is my first Power Query project. I have a pseudo-represented code of a mod from [this article](https://datachant.com/2016/06/27/cursor-based-pagination-power-query/) shown below:

```
// Attempt at pagination
let

    // Define some variables
    _url = "https://www.randomURLNOTWORKING.com/events?before=9999999999",
    _headers = [authorization="Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"],
    _iterations = 3,

    // Function - Get the results of current page
    FnGetOnePage =
        (_url) as record =>
            let
                // Get the JSON response of the current page
                Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(_url, [Headers=_headers])),
                ///////////////////////////////// Below is not appropriate for my use case
                //data = Source[data],
                //next = Source[paging][next],

                // Return the "data" (I'm assuming it should be in unpacked form?) and the "next" pagination link
                res = [Data=data, Next=next]
            in
                res,

    // Function - Generate a list of results
    // Not sure if this is what my use case needs either but leaving as pseudo
    GeneratedList =
        List.Generate(
            ()=>[i=0, res = FnGetOnePage(_url)],
            each [i]<_iterations and [res][Data]<>null,
            each [i=[i]+1, res = FnGetOnePage([res][Next])],
            each [res][Data]),

    // Unpack all of the results
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromRecords(GeneratedList),
    #"Expanded _pagination" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "_pagination", {"next"}, {"_pagination.next"}),
    #"Expanded _links" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _pagination", "_links", {"self"}, {"_links.self"}),
    #"Expanded _results" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded _links", "_results"),
    #"Expanded _results1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results", "_results", {"_links", "id", "type", "emitted_at", "conversation", "source", "target"}, {"_results._links", "_results.id", "_results.type", "_results.emitted_at", "_results.conversation", "_results.source", "_results.target"}),
    #"Expanded _results._links" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results1", "_results._links", {"self"}, {"_results._links.self"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results._links", "_results.conversation", {"_links", "id", "subject", "status", "assignee", "recipient", "tags", "links", "created_at", "is_private", "scheduled_reminders", "metadata"}, {"_results.conversation._links", "_results.conversation.id", "_results.conversation.subject", "_results.conversation.status", "_results.conversation.assignee", "_results.conversation.recipient", "_results.conversation.tags", "_results.conversation.links", "_results.conversation.created_at", "_results.conversation.is_private", "_results.conversation.scheduled_reminders", "_results.conversation.metadata"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation._links" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation", "_results.conversation._links", {"self", "related"}, {"_results.conversation._links.self", "_results.conversation._links.related"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation._links.related" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation._links", "_results.conversation._links.related", {"events", "followers", "messages", "comments", "inboxes", "last_message"}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.events", "_results.conversation._links.related.followers", "_results.conversation._links.related.messages", "_results.conversation._links.related.comments", "_results.conversation._links.related.inboxes", "_results.conversation._links.related.last_message"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation.recipient" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation._links.related", "_results.conversation.recipient", {"_links", "name", "handle", "role"}, {"_results.conversation.recipient._links", "_results.conversation.recipient.name", "_results.conversation.recipient.handle", "_results.conversation.recipient.role"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation.recipient._links" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation.recipient", "_results.conversation.recipient._links", {"related"}, {"_results.conversation.recipient._links.related"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation.recipient._links.related" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation.recipient._links", "_results.conversation.recipient._links.related", {"contact"}, {"_results.conversation.recipient._links.related.contact"}),
    #"Expanded _results.conversation.metadata" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation.recipient._links.related", "_results.conversation.metadata", {}, {}),
    #"Expanded _results.source" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.conversation.metadata", "_results.source", {"_meta", "data"}, {"_results.source._meta", "_results.source.data"}),
    #"Expanded _results.source._meta" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.source", "_results.source._meta", {"type"}, {"_results.source._meta.type"}),
    #"Expanded _results.target" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.source._meta", "_results.target", {"_meta", "data"}, {"_results.target._meta", "_results.target.data"}),
    #"Expanded _results.target._meta" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.target", "_results.target._meta", {"type"}, {"_results.target._meta.type"}),
    #"Expanded _results.target.data" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.target._meta", "_results.target.data", {"_links", "id", "type", "is_inbound", "name", "highlight", "is_private", "is_visible_in_conversation_lists", "updated_at", "created_at", "blurb", "body", "text", "error_type", "version", "subject", "draft_mode", "metadata", "posted_at", "author", "recipients", "attachments", "signature", "is_draft", "email", "username", "first_name", "last_name", "is_admin", "is_available", "is_blocked", "custom_fields"}, {"_results.target.data._links", "_results.target.data.id", "_results.target.data.type", "_results.target.data.is_inbound", "_results.target.data.name", "_results.target.data.highlight", "_results.target.data.is_private", "_results.target.data.is_visible_in_conversation_lists", "_results.target.data.updated_at", "_results.target.data.created_at", "_results.target.data.blurb", "_results.target.data.body", "_results.target.data.text", "_results.target.data.error_type", "_results.target.data.version", "_results.target.data.subject", "_results.target.data.draft_mode", "_results.target.data.metadata", "_results.target.data.posted_at", "_results.target.data.author", "_results.target.data.recipients", "_results.target.data.attachments", "_results.target.data.signature", "_results.target.data.is_draft", "_results.target.data.email", "_results.target.data.username", "_results.target.data.first_name", "_results.target.data.last_name", "_results.target.data.is_admin", "_results.target.data.is_available", "_results.target.data.is_blocked", "_results.target.data.custom_fields"}),
    #"Expanded _results.target.data._links" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.target.data", "_results.target.data._links", {"self", "related"}, {"_results.target.data._links.self", "_results.target.data._links.related"}),
    #"Expanded _results.target.data._links.related" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.target.data._links", "_results.target.data._links.related", {"conversation", "message_seen", "mentions", "inboxes", "conversations", "owner", "parent_tag", "children", "message_replied_to"}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.conversation", "_results.target.data._links.related.message_seen", "_results.target.data._links.related.mentions", "_results.target.data._links.related.inboxes", "_results.target.data._links.related.conversations", "_results.target.data._links.related.owner", "_results.target.data._links.related.parent_tag", "_results.target.data._links.related.children", "_results.target.data._links.related.message_replied_to"}),
    #"Expanded _results.target.data.metadata" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.target.data._links.related", "_results.target.data.metadata", {}, {}),
    #"Expanded _results.target.data.custom_fields" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded _results.target.data.metadata", "_results.target.data.custom_fields", {}, {}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded _results.target.data.custom_fields",{{"_pagination.next", type text}, {"_links.self", type text}, {"_results._links.self", type text}, {"_results.id", type text}, {"_results.type", type text}, {"_results.emitted_at", type number}, {"_results.conversation._links.self", type text}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.events", type text}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.followers", type text}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.messages", type text}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.comments", type text}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.inboxes", type text}, {"_results.conversation._links.related.last_message", type text}, {"_results.conversation.id", type text}, {"_results.conversation.subject", type text}, {"_results.conversation.status", type text}, {"_results.conversation.assignee", type any}, {"_results.conversation.recipient._links.related.contact", type text}, {"_results.conversation.recipient.name", type text}, {"_results.conversation.recipient.handle", type text}, {"_results.conversation.recipient.role", type text}, {"_results.conversation.tags", type any}, {"_results.conversation.links", type any}, {"_results.conversation.created_at", type number}, {"_results.conversation.is_private", type logical}, {"_results.conversation.scheduled_reminders", type any}, {"_results.source._meta.type", type text}, {"_results.source.data", type any}, {"_results.target._meta.type", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.self", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.conversation", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.message_seen", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.mentions", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.inboxes", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.conversations", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.owner", type text}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.parent_tag", type any}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.children", type any}, {"_results.target.data._links.related.message_replied_to", type text}, {"_results.target.data.id", type text}, {"_results.target.data.type", type text}, {"_results.target.data.is_inbound", type logical}, {"_results.target.data.name", type text}, {"_results.target.data.highlight", type any}, {"_results.target.data.is_private", type logical}, {"_results.target.data.is_visible_in_conversation_lists", type logical}, {"_results.target.data.updated_at", type number}, {"_results.target.data.created_at", type number}, {"_results.target.data.blurb", type text}, {"_results.target.data.body", type text}, {"_results.target.data.text", type text}, {"_results.target.data.error_type", type any}, {"_results.target.data.version", type any}, {"_results.target.data.subject", type text}, {"_results.target.data.draft_mode", type any}, {"_results.target.data.posted_at", type number}, {"_results.target.data.author", type any}, {"_results.target.data.recipients", type any}, {"_results.target.data.attachments", type any}, {"_results.target.data.signature", type any}, {"_results.target.data.is_draft", type logical}, {"_results.target.data.email", type text}, {"_results.target.data.username", type text}, {"_results.target.data.first_name", type text}, {"_results.target.data.last_name", type text}, {"_results.target.data.is_admin", type logical}, {"_results.target.data.is_available", type logical}, {"_results.target.data.is_blocked", type logical}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Obviously this code does not work, and I think this is over complicating what I'm looking to do.

A thing to note that might help the developer is that the NEXT request DOES NOT make use of a "page number" or anything, so I don't need to access `i` in the iterative loop at all. Basically the flow should look like this:

1. Start a `for` loop up to `_iterations` in duration
2. Request the content from the `_url`
3. Unpack the details of the response using all those `#`'s to get it into proper table format (if necessary at this stage?)
4. Request the content from the `_pagination.next` link from the previous request.
5. Repeat steps 3-4 until iteration is done.
6. Review the table
7. Profit!

So the code from the article I'm sourcing is likely NOT the best way to go about this, and the code from the other articles seems like overkill. These are the articles I've looked at so far, and I have a conceptual understanding of what needs to happen, but syntactically I'm just not there yet.

https://datachant.com/2016/06/27/cursor-based-pagination-power-query/

https://medium.com/@marktiedemann/how-to-do-pagination-in-power-query-430460c17c78

https://gist.github.com/MarkTiedemann/f667c75cc3d054b9b2bce25ea08bc631

https://comertechnology.com/cw-manage-getting-started-with-powerbi-the-update/?fbclid=IwAR0ReCaaX7KgXR8CsozWsbIzCH1vzLXM0C3ZQFAbBKoVjGAUEJImNnj9kLo

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Pagination-of-a-REST-API-in-Power-Query-using-M/td-p/1901067

**UPDATE**
To help further describe what I'm looking for here, I've created a working example of 1 API call in Python shown below:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.randomURLNOTWORKING.com/events?before=9999999999"

payload={}
headers = {
  'authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

RESPONSE

```
{
  "_pagination": {
    "next": "https://www.randomURLNOTWORKING.com.com/events?before=9999999999&page_token=XXXX22222"
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": "https://www.randomURLNOTWORKING.com.com/events?before=9999999999"
  },
  "_results": [
    {
      "_links": {
        "self": "https://www.randomURLNOTWORKING.com.com/2"
      },
      "id": "evt_2tejxwp8",
      "type": "assign",
      "emitted_at": 1664213539.745,
      "conversation": {
        "_links": {
          "self": "https://www.randomURLNOTWORKING.com.com/3",
          "related": {
            "events": "https://www.randomURLNOTWORKING.com.com/4"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This response has been truncated and any business info hidden.

So we can see, the nested dictionary/JSON response where the `response["_pagination"]["next"]` value is the next link to use in the next iteration of the loop. So, the Python version of what this would look like looks something like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.randomURLNOTWORKING.com/events?before=9999999999"
_iterations = 10

payload={}
headers = {
  'authorization': 'Bearer XXXXXXXXXX'
}

# Perform the first request
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)

# Start iterating
for _ in range(_iterations):
    
    next_url = response["_pagination"]["next"]
    response = requests.request("GET", next_url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    print(response.text)
```

This works, however what's missing here is the "expanding" of all the nested JSON dictionaries into their own columns, which I've already accounted for in the OQ, I am just unclear about how to program this syntax in Power Query.

My goal is that once an answer is found here, it'll help others perform pagination with Power Query, where your "next" link is inside a nested JSON dict. Hopefully someone who knows Python even a little bit can see this and translate it to Power Query for me to test.

Comment: The purpose of Stackoverflow is to assemble solutions to generic coding problems
that can be applied to multiple use cases and not to provide individual consulting service.
Please boil your problem down to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others could benefit from a solution too.

Comment: Could a fellow PowerQuery user write some code and test it in their local machine, including all the tables and a representative data set? Readers undoubtedly want to help, but I am not sure they can if they can't replicate the problem.

Comment: If that is not possible then I wonder if I would agree with @Peter, and suggest looking into obtaining hourly consulting, where the problem can be demonstrated over a screen-share.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot share the token for the API which would be needed for a MRE. However, I think what I will do is construct a working example of what I'm looking to do in Python as that's what I'm more familiar with, and then can repost (with examples of the data being returned by the API for reproduction), asking to simply convert the Python code to Power Query. I will tackle the Python stuff tonight so if the question can remain open for the time being, I will repost the question with code/samples of data and we can go from there. Thanks!

Comment: OK. I don't know this area well, but in the interests of ensuring you don't do a lot of work in the wrong direction, bear in mind that "plz convert this code for me" requests don't usually do well here. If the actual problem you are trying to solve could make use of that labour, then great, but I would not want you to go to great efforts, only to find that the resulting Stack Overflow question is of a type that is generally received poorly by the readership.

Comment: That's understood, however the problem is fairly applicable to others as many have asked similar questions about pagination in Power Query, the trick with my question is that the "Next" link is buried in the response of the API call and needs to be "expanded" into a proper column before we can see what it is, something that really isn't described well in the articles I've posted. Since I cannot share the API, the most I can do is provide a sample of the data being returned, which will be way easier in Python since I can actually print it out! lol.

Comment: It simply boils down to needing a `for` loop to iterate through a number of API calls, utilizing the "Next" link of each response, which you can get after it's been "expanded". This really shouldn't require access to the API anyway (if someone were to ask me to program a `for` loop in Python for this, I could do it without needing access to the API?), which is why I chose to post it. Hope that clarifies a few things, but I will see what I can do in terms of further clarification using Python later tonight. Thanks!

Comment: OQ updated to show working Python equivalent. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out, working code is below:

```
// Attempt at pagination
let

    // Define some variables
    _url = "https://www.randomURLNOTWORKING.com/events?before=9999999999",
    _headers = [authorization="Bearer XXXXXXXXX"],
    _iterations = 3,

    // Function - Get the results of current page
    FnGetOnePage =
        (input_url) as record =>
            let
                // Get the JSON response of the current page
                Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(input_url, [Headers=_headers])),

                data = Source[_results],
                next = Source[_pagination][next],

                // Return the "data"
                res = [Data=data, Next=next]
            in
                res,

    // Function - Generate a list of results
    GeneratedList =
        List.Generate(
            ()=>[i=0, res = FnGetOnePage(_url)],
            each [i]<_iterations and [res][Data]<>null,
            each [i=[i]+1, res = FnGetOnePage([res][Next])],
            each [res][Data]),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(GeneratedList, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

The majority of the "expanding" will be done just above the last `in` line, however this can be done in the Power Query Editor visually as needed.

So what I've done is create an iteration, where I query the endpoint `_iterations` times, and in the `FnGetOnePage` function, I return the `[_pagination][next]` link, along with the un-expanded `_results` data.

After iteration is done, all of the unpacking is done from the `GeneratedList` variable which has all the info I need to expand. Pretty basic I would have thought, but thanks for letting me work this out, hopefully it helps others!